# Is my invitation based file access authorization scheme worthwhile?

Tags: authorization, file-access

I need to allow users to upload files with sensitive data to a server, then invite other authenticated users to access specific files.

This is my proposed solution:

Each user will have his own folder to which he uploads files, and the parent folder will have an .htaccess with `deny all` to block direct access.  (This already works well.)

Then, an invited user will get a generated SHA1 invitation id and the url will be something like `download/[sha1]/file` and I can then use my controller to check if this invitation exists in the database for this authenticated user.  If it does, I get the file and based on the file extension I give the appropriate header for file download.

ex:

```
localhost/[whatever]/download/[some_hash]/test.txt

invitation_table
invite_id         - unique ID
invite_token      - sha1 which will be generated by his unique email concatenated with other data
invite_invited    - logged user invite
invite_user       - user who invited the user
```

Based on the hash, I query the db and get the invite_user data and then I know in which directory I have to get the file because there can be multiple files on the server with the same name in different directories.

Is this is a good approach?

Comment: Whoever down-votes please explain why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of SHA-1 is somewhat risky. A scheme based on hashed tokens, like your propose, can be done securely. However, there are various subtleties to doing it right. Considering you are going to do a database lookup for each file access, there is no need to rely on hash tokens.

Instead I suggest a much simpler system where the invitation_table simply consists of file_id and user_id. When a file owner invites a user, add a row to the table. When a user requests a file, check whether the requesting user has an entry in the table for that file_id.